# Custom content provider access from another app

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-permissions

I have two apps. one of the two has a custom content provider which works like a charm.

APP A -> The one with the provider

APP B -> The one that needs the data from the provider

Everything works fine in this scenario:

1st : Install app A

2nd: Install app B

However when I do it like this:

1st: Install app B

2nd: Install app A

I get the error :

```
09-19 13:07:22.576: E/AndroidRuntime(14621): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider 
uk.co.ringsizer.ui.BirthProvider from ProcessRecord{450c14c8 14621:uk.co.gemtv/u0a360} 
(pid=14621, uid=10360) requires com.eir.provider.Size.READ_DATABASE 
or com.eir.provider.Size.WRITE_DATABASE
```

My permissions are clearly stated in the manifest file and they are  correct since it works if I install the apps in a different order.

It's the first time I'm using Content provider and I am relatively new to Android so the problem might be obvious to more experienced developers.

Any ideas? Has anybody else experienced the same issue before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: catch this exception and tell the user to reinstall the app ... it is the only thing that you can do with this ... http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25906

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app that defines the custom `<permission>` must be installed before the app that requests it via `<uses-permission>`. If they are installed in the wrong order, the `<uses-permission>` app does not get the permission and must be uninstalled and reinstalled.

[Custom permissions in general are risky for SDK apps](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md).

Comment: Since PUBLIC shared preferences got deprecated the only thing I think i can use is content providers. Do you  have something similar to suggest?

Comment: @user3328051: Your problem isn't with using a `ContentProvider` -- any IPC involving custom permissions would encounter the same issue. Moreover, your app with `<uses-permission>` would need to handle cases where the user doesn't want the other app, cannot install the other app (e.g., it is incompatible with their device), installs and later uninstalls the other app, etc.

Comment: Sorry to poke after 4 years but,
How to handle SecurityException when using LoaderManager

Comment: @Pankaj: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] and a complete explanation of your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that BOTH apps have the permission attribute in the manifest.

```
<permission android:name="com.example.permission.READ" />
```

I had only the use-permission attribute in the consuming app, and had exactly this problem. It'll work if the content provider app is installed first, but will fail if the content provider app is installed second.

When the consuming client app has the permission attribute as well, it will work regardless of app install order.

Comment: Just to clarify, the permission attribute defines the permission. In order for this to work, both apps must be signed with the same signature to be able to define the same permission. And in case both apps are signed with the same signature, this will solve the problem with installation order that CommonsWare described